# insert external css file in to a regular html sheet

Tags: html, css

someone created a html/css ebay template for me. He made one file with the html and linked it to another file with the css. I want to take all that css and insert it into the html file. I dont want to have the css external, I want it to be internal. How do I go about doing this?

Comment: Why do you want to make it internal? What problem are you trying to solve? Just because?

Comment: i am using a 3rd party software that will use it as a template to map alot of information through it, and I feel that it would be easiest for them if it were all in one place.

Comment: Good info - you should add that to your question. While you're in there, fix your capitalization and punctuation, per the guidelines: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is very easy to accomplish..

Just place the contents of the CSS File into the HTML between style tags.

```
<style>
 Contents of the CSS File
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<html>
  <head>
    <style>
      ..contents of that external css file   
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>

  </body>
</html>
```